# Average dialy activity - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Vendors (
    VendorID : INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    AVG_Dialy_Sale : REAL NOT NULL,
    ...
);
CREATE TABLE SoldStuff (
    Vendor references VENDORS,
    Date_Sold Date NOT NULL,
    StuffID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);
```

The first one holds general data about vendors - what's their ID, how much they sell a day and some other values.
The second table holds information about sold products: who, what and when sold something. Each line stands for different, one product. The products are unique and may be sold only once.

The question: how to update table `VENDORS` so that it holds average number of products sold every day by vendors?

I tried to get it like that:

-make table `WHO | HOW_MANY` which holds "How many items have sold this vendor" instead of IDs, but the values are scattered in many rows - we must use `SUM` to get the desired value.

-I make a table `WHO | FIRST_DAY` which holds the first day every vendor sold something.

-The next step would be joining those tables, and putting `SUM(HOW_MANY) / (NOW() - FIRST_DAY + 1) GROUP BY VENDOR` into table `VENDORS`, but at this point I am stuck.

Here is the SQL statement that gives the table `WHO | FIRST_ITEM_SOLD_DATE | HOW_MANY_ITEMS_SOLD`:

```
WITH CoolTable AS (
    SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', DateSold) AS Date__, 
        COUNT(StuffID) AS HowManyItemsSold, 
        Vendor 
    FROM SoldStuff 
    GROUP BY Vendor, DATE_TRUNC('day', Vendor.DateSold)
), 
FirstDates AS (
    SELECT Vendor, 
        MIN(Date__) AS FirstItemSoldDate 
    FROM CoolTable 
    GROUP BY Vendor
) 
SELECT CoolTable.Vendor, 
    FirstItemSoldDate 
FROM CoolTable JOIN FirstDates ON CoolTable.Vendor = FirstDates.Vendor;
```

Note: it gives the same date in every row with the same vendor, but to get sum of all products sold by each vendor one must perform `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableIAmStuckOn GROUP BY Vendor;`.

`count(distinct date_sold)` may not be used "like that" - if a person have sold only 5 items two years ago his AVG_DIALY_SALE should be much worse than the one's who started selling a week ago and sold 2 items.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Rather than *updating* vendors, I strongly recommend creating a materialized view (either built-in 9.3 feature, or maintained with triggers) that keeps track of average sales. `create table vendor_averages(vendor_id integer, sales_average bigint)`. Try to keep your autogenerated data separate. For that matter, you might as well start with an ordinary view and see if that performs well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a correlated subquery instead:

```
update vendors
    set avg_daily_sale = (select count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct date_sold)
                          from stuffsold ss
                          where ss.vendorId = vendors.vendorId
                         );
```

The subquery is an alternative way of calculating the average without a subquery.

EDIT:

Oh, if you are trying for a "sales rate" then

```
update vendors
    set avg_daily_sale = (select count(*) * 1.0 / (date(CURRENT_DATE) - min(date(date_sold)))
                          from stuffsold ss
                          where ss.vendorId = vendors.vendorId
                         );
```

Comment: The point is, that `count(distinct date_sold)` may not be used - if a person have sold only 5 items two years ago his AVG_DIALY_SALE should be much worse than the one's who started selling a week ago and sold 2 items. Updated it on post.

Comment: You forgot `GROUP BY` and it says that "column `date_` must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or be used in an aggreagate function" and this is the point where I had no idea what to do and how to fix it.

Comment: @user2420535 . . . I didn't forget the `group by`, I forgot the `min()`.